# Reset password link not send in user mail laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

In my laravel project i used `php artisan make:auth command`. When i sent a reset password link it stored in my `resource/storage/logs` file. How can i sent it user email?
Please give me a complete solution.

Here is my default controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller
{
    use ResetsPasswords;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }


}
```

Comment: The complete solution is mentioned in the Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#resetting-passwords

Comment: I saw this. But i can't send resend link user email.

Comment: You need to share your code first before we can help.

Comment: I update my post.